Aligning text with in fullwidth sections with boxed sections - Elementor
So I am working on a Wordpress website and using Elementor Pro as my primary page builder. I have a design layout which uses full-width sections for titles and content using boxed sections. I am struggling with aligning text in the full width section and boxed sections. As you can see in the screenshot.
I would like the headings and text to aligned with the same start line but setting the paddings with in the title (full-width) sections does messes up the aligning as soon as the screen resolutions changes, so i wanted to know if there is a way I can fix the font-alignment so the text starts at the same spot?
I have tried adjusting the margin and paddings in the full width sections but it doesn't work for all resolutions on PC.
